# Subclassing wxControl

Tags: wxwidgets

My goal is to make a control with two buttons, similar to Toolbar tool with `wxITEM_DROPDOWN` set.

I use the following strategy:

```
CDropDownTool::CDropDownTool(wxWindow* parent, int id, const wxBitmap& bmptool, const wxBitmap& bmpDrop, const wxString& tooltip) :
    wxControl(parent, id, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxBORDER_NONE)
{
    m_BMPTool = bmptool;
    m_BMPDrop = bmpDrop;

    m_ID = id;

    wxSize sz1 = m_BMPTool.GetSize();
    wxSize sz2 = m_BMPDrop.GetSize();

    SetClientSize(wxSize(sz1.x + sz2.x + GAP, std::max(sz1.y, sz2.y)));

    Bind(wxEVT_PAINT, &CDropDownTool::OnPaint, this);
    Bind(wxEVT_LEFT_DOWN, &CDropDownTool::OnLeftDown, this);
}
```

And then to paint the control:

```
void CDropDownTool::OnPaint(wxPaintEvent& event)
{
    wxPaintDC pdc(this);

    wxSize szBMP = m_BMPTool.GetSize();
    auto Rect = GetClientRect();

    int y = (Rect.GetHeight() - szBMP.GetHeight()) / 2;

    wxPoint TL = Rect.GetTopLeft();
    TL.y = y;

    m_Tool = wxRect(TL, szBMP);

    pdc.DrawBitmap(m_BMPTool, TL);

    wxPoint TL2 = TL;
    TL2.x += m_BMPTool.GetSize().x + GAP;

    m_DropTool = wxRect(TL2, m_BMPDrop.GetSize());

    pdc.DrawBitmap(m_BMPDrop, TL2);
}
```

Things work but I have the following related questions:

1. When the mouse is over, it is not highlighted like the other controls (such as button etc...). How to add highlighting effect?
2. I add the control to ToolBar and I realized the overriden member function `DoGetBestSize` is never called.

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: For the first issue, you can handle the mouse events wxEVT_ENTER_WINDOW and wxEVT_LEAVE_WINDOW and modify the paint handler to draw the highlighting when the mouse is over the control.  Unfortunately, I don't know the sizing functions work when a control is in a toolbar, so I can't help with the second issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to catch `wxEVT_MOUSE_ENTER` and `_LEAVE` events to be notified when the mouse cursor enters and leaves the window and be able to refresh your button -- and then take into account whether the mouse is over it or not when repainting.

`DoGetBestSize()` is only used if the best size of the control needs to be determined. If you specify its size when creating it, it's not going to be called.

Comment: Even if I comment out `SetClientSize`, `DoGetBestSize()` is not called either. I am adding the control to the toolbar using `AddControl`, maybe it is the case since sizers are not used.